# Display text from controller AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, error-handling, datepicker

I have a datepicker and when the user enters an invalid date I want to display a proper message

```
$scope.setDate = function(startDate, endDate) {
        $rootScope.startDate = $scope.startDateL;
        $rootScope.endDate = $scope.endDateL;

        if(($rootScope.startDate == undefined) || ($rootScope.endDate == undefined)){
            console.log("choose a valid date");
            $mdDialog.show({
                cotnroller: DatePickerErrorController,
                templateUrl : 'components/jags-date-picker-select/jags-date-picker-modal-valid-date.html',
                parent : angular.element(document.body),
                clickOutsideToClose:true
            }).then(function(answer) {
                console.log("Fff");
            }, function() {
        });
```

If the date that I want to set is undefined that means that the user has not entered one I want to display a modal with a proper text.

This is the controller for my modal

```
function DatePickerErrorController($scope, $rootScope){

    $scope.text = function(){
        return "Some text";

    }

}
```

I want to do some checkings in my DatePickerErrorController. Something like if the startdate is undefined return some text.

This is the modal that should be displayed with a proper message.

```
  <!-- Modal -->
 <md-dialog aria-label="Date Picker">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">{{"Error message" | translate}}</h4>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-header -->
        <div class="modal-body">
            {{text}}
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-body -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
</md-dialog>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

Now, the problem is that the modal shows up but it is not displaying "Some text". The modal is just blank. Have I done something wrong? This is not the correct way to display a text in html? Somebody with any ideas ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just write $scope.text = "Some Text";  text u defined is a function. Try editing this also in $mdDialog.show() {}

Comment: it just displays blank...

Comment: Try editing this also in $mdDialog.show() {controller: DatePickerErrorController}  . u have mispelled controller

Comment: @Sasank: Oh my god! thank you very much :)

Comment: @SasankSunkavalli: Now, I want to write a function, such as $scope.text = function(){ if($rootScope.startDate == undefined) return "Some text"}. Does it work like that ?

Comment: and the html remains the same

Comment: Yeah it will work , u just have to write this in html <div class="modal-body" ng-bind="text()">
        </div>, let me know if it works

Comment: @SasankSunkavalli: It works! Thanks a lot! :-)